# All urls are not working, it is accidently deleted,

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, url, 404, delete

Yesterday, I accidentally deleted unnecessary backup files from the public_html folder and deleted other important files as well.

Since then, the main home page of the website has been well displayed, but no admin page or any other page has been entered.

The following error appears: Could you help us see what file is deleted and the result is like this?

Thank you.

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

> exception.log

```
    [2020-02-11 12:21:11] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: Cannot read contents from file "/home/devclonekbethos/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/savio2/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/devclonekbethos/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/savio2/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149

Stack trace:

    #0 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Read.php(207): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->fileGetContents('/home/devclonek...', NULL, NULL)

    #1 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(285): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read->readFile('mixins.min.js')
    #2 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(151): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->createChain(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File), '/home/devclonek...', 'mixins.min.js')
    #3 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(121): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->preProcess(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
    #4 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php(163): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->getContent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
    #5 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/Direct.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getContent()
    #6 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/Direct.php(52): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\Direct->composeMergedContent(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
    #7 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/FileExists.php(44): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\Direct->merge(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
    #8 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Merged.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\FileExists->merge(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
    #9 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Merged.php(157): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged->initialize()
    #10 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(358): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged->rewind()
    #11 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(251): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetHtml('<script  type="...', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged))
    #12 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(226): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetGroup(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))
    #13 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(99): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssets(Array)
    #14 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(235): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderHeadContent()
    #15 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
    #16 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
    #17 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
    #18 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
    #19 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
    #20 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
    #21 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
    #22 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
    #23 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
    #24 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
    #25 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
    #26 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
    #27 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
    #28 {main} [] []
```

> system.log

```
[2020-02-10 07:31:25] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 [] []
[2020-02-10 07:52:01] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _product in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary.phtml on line 76 [] []
```

> debug.log

```
[2020-02-11 05:16:06] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 {"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 06:00:08] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 06:00:08] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 06:00:08] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BLOCK_HTML","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 06:00:08] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category","catalog_product","BLOCK_HTML"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 08:20:56] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 {"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 11:34:53] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: Cannot read contents from file "/home/devclonekbethos/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/savio2/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/devclonekbethos/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/savio2/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149
Stack trace:
#0 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Read.php(207): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->fileGetContents('/home/devclonek...', NULL, NULL)
#1 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(285): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read->readFile('mixins.min.js')
#2 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(151): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->createChain(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File), '/home/devclonek...', 'mixins.min.js')
#3 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(121): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->preProcess(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#4 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php(163): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->getContent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#5 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/Direct.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getContent()
#6 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/Direct.php(52): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\Direct->composeMergedContent(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#7 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/FileExists.php(44): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\Direct->merge(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#8 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Merged.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\FileExists->merge(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#9 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Merged.php(157): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged->initialize()
#10 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(358): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged->rewind()
#11 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(251): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetHtml('<script  type="...', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged))
#12 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(226): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetGroup(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))
#13 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(99): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssets(Array)
#14 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(235): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderHeadContent()
#15 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#16 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#17 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#18 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#19 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#20 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#21 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#22 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#23 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#24 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#25 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#26 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#27 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#28 {main} {"is_exception":true} []
[2020-02-11 11:52:41] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 {"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 12:21:11] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: Cannot read contents from file "/home/devclonekbethos/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/savio2/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js" Warning!file_get_contents(/home/devclonekbethos/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/savio2/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149
Stack trace:
#0 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Read.php(207): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->fileGetContents('/home/devclonek...', NULL, NULL)
#1 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(285): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read->readFile('mixins.min.js')
#2 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(151): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->createChain(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File), '/home/devclonek...', 'mixins.min.js')
#3 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(121): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->preProcess(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#4 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php(163): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->getContent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#5 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/Direct.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getContent()
#6 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/Direct.php(52): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\Direct->composeMergedContent(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#7 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeStrategy/FileExists.php(44): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\Direct->merge(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#8 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Merged.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\FileExists->merge(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#9 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Merged.php(157): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged->initialize()
#10 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(358): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged->rewind()
#11 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(251): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetHtml('<script  type="...', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Merged))
#12 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(226): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetGroup(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))
#13 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(99): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssets(Array)
#14 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(235): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderHeadContent()
#15 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#16 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#17 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#18 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#19 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#20 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#21 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#22 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#23 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#24 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#25 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#26 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#27 /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#28 {main} {"is_exception":true} []
[2020-02-11 13:27:37] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":[],"mode":"all"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:27:37] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":[],"mode":"all"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:27:37] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:28:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:28:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:29:25] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:34:15] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:34:26] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:36:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:37:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:37:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:46:04] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 {"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:57:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 13:57:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 14:31:28] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 {"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 14:33:30] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 {"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 14:38:08] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 {"is_exception":false} []
[2020-02-11 16:09:44] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: _productType in /home/devclonekbethos/public_html/app/code/Appmerce/MultiplesOfX/view/frontend/templates/addtocart.phtml on line 16 {"is_exception":false} []
```

Comment: Can you please share the error in log file.
Also, do you have the backup on your hosting account ?(Just for a last chance)

Comment: i added some codes.. this is test site's problem but very important to us.. thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you "just" deleted the assets. 
Run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` to regenerate them and flush your cache afterwards. 
If you are lucky this was the only problem and you should be good. If not try to get a backup by your hosting provider.

If you know what you do you could also just update your complete system by running a full update. This should install every code related dependecies. If you are not 100% sure you will maybe do more harm than good.

```
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```